# global NSMutableArray variable xcode

Tags: xcode, nsmutablearray, global-variables

I am making an iPhone application that goes through a set of viewcontrollers that collect data from user input. At the end of the views I encapsulate all of the data in an customized object called GELObject. Now I need to save this data in a NSMutableArray somewhere so that it can be accessed by a tableviewcontroller that is another branch off of the rootviewcontroller. I was thinking a global variable from the tableviewcontroller, but I did some research and I am reading about singleton's in the appdelegate. Some guidance would be greatly appreciated and if you're feeling extra generous a quick explanation of how to make and use singleton's because it is intriguing me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manage a singleton you create a global variable (can be restricted to one file's scope with `static`) with an initial sentinel value of `nil`, and use a class method to create the singleton on the first call.

For example:

```
static Something* globalSomething = nil;

@implementation Something

+ (id)
sharedSomething
{
  if (! globalSomething)
  {
    /* can use different initializer if necessary */
    globalSomething = [[[self class] allocWithZone:NULL] init];
  }
  return globalSomething;
}

. . .

@end
```

Comment: So I should put this into my app delegate class? And after that how would I call it from the tableviewcontroller or the view controller at the end of the navigations?

Comment: This type of method would be a member of whichever class should have the singleton (in this case, the class that has to allocate a mutable array).  You call it on the class itself, e.g. in this example, using `[Something sharedSomething]` (which returns a `Something*`).  The initializer would allocate the array and the array would be declared as a field in the class.